# Picasa: automaticly change image size in the site

Tags: javascript, html, picasa, fluid-images

I keep the images of my site in Picasa... as we know we can set size of picture like this.

http://lh5.ggpht.com/-i97UI0TXchE/UatpZd-E3tI/AAAAAAAAAFg/HUu-QK63ce0/w900-h0/running-sml.jpg

The part `w900-h0`  means that, the picture size is: `width` 900px and the `height` 0 (auto).

And so I need change this url, (acctualy the part  `w900-h0`)  of the image automaticly depending of the viewport of the device, I know that I can make images fluid just set them max-widht:100%; via css, but in that case the picture's size is not getting smaller, and it just visually small.

How can I change the part  `w900-h0` via java-script, for example when viewport is 480 the url is changed   `w300-h0` and so on.

Comment: What have you tried? Which part are you having trouble with i.e. how to calculate the sizes, how to replace the image's `src` property, how to find which images to change...?

Comment: ok, so

my images always in div with class `the-image`, by default the width in the src of the image  will be 800 (`w800`), so, when the viewport is smaller than 900, the part of the url (src of the image), `w800` is change to `w400`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this to change image width in `document.ready` state:

```
imageWidth = $(window).width();
$("#my_image").attr("src","http://lh5.ggpht.com/-i97UI0TXchE/UatpZd-E3tI/AAAAAAAAAFg/HUu-QK63ce0/w"+imageWidth+"-h0/running-sml.jpg");
```

Function `$(window).resize()` can also be helpful to resize dynamicaly.

**Update:**

If you want to do this for more than one image:

```
imageWidth = $(window).width();
$(".imageForResize").each(function() {
  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr('src').replace('w900-h0', 'w'+imageWidth+'-h0'));
});
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4Sey/)

Comment: but every time there will be another picture,  so I can't do it like this, the picture's url every time will be change